# Problema con Convert.FromBase64String en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Un cordial saludo. Tengo un problema con el método **Convert.FromBase64String** en C# y si alguien pudiera ayudarme le agradecería muchísimo.

Estoy haciendo una aplicación ASP.NET y uso un método para la validación de la autenticación, en el Visual Studio compila todo bien sin ningún error o advertencia, pero cuando ejecuto el programa e ingreso el usuario y contraseña y doy Aceptar para autenticarme me muestra el siguiente error:

> El código de usuario no controló System.FormatException
> HResult=-2146233033
>
> Message=Longitud no válida para una matriz o cadena de caracteres
> Base-64.
>
> Source=mscorlib
>
> StackTrace: en System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
>
> en System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
>
> en System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)`

El error me muestra en la siguiente línea de código:

```
(string hashValue;)
byte[] hashBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(hashValue);
```

(hashValue en sql = `[Password] [varchar]500 NOT NULL`).

Al respecto estoy usando:

- Win 8.1 x64,
- Visual Studio Community 2015 V 14.0.25431.01 Update 3,
- SQL Server Express 2014
- .Net Framework 4.6.1 para los proyectos y
- Google Chrome Versión 84.0.4147.125 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

Intenté algunas opciones pero me muestra el mismo error, por ejemplo:

```
var hashBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(hashValue); // NO FUNCIONÓ

byte[] hashBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(hashValue.Trim('\0'));  // NO FUNCIONÓ

var response = hashValue.Substring(1, hashValue.Length - 2).Replace(@"\/", "/"); // NO FUNCIONÓ

byte[] hashBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(response); // NO FUNCIONÓ
```

Muchas gracias...

Comment: estás usando el base64 como método de encriptación ? no es buena idea, existen métodos específicos para realizar eso, algo básico podría ser el MD5 y algo más avanzado los algoritmos SHA-128 y SHA-256

Comment: el de arriba tiene razon, pero como no es lo que preguntas, tu problema esta en el tamaño de tu campo en sql, prueba con el tipo varbinarymax en sql.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Intenté con el varbinary(max) pero tendría que cambiar mi código y en la tabla me muestra que ese campo empieza con "0x..." (supongo que es hexadecimal).  Voy a seguir el consejo de cambiar de algoritmo (SHA-512) , antes usé el SHA-256 y funcionó bien, ahora voy a usar ese no más. Muchas gracias...